# Conditional Joint PDF of Multivariate Normal

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let $Z_1$, $Z_2$, and $Z_3$ be independent standard normal random variables. Let $$X_1=2Z_1 + Z_2 + 2,$$ $$X_2 = \ \ Z_1- 2Z_2 + 1,$$$$X_3 = -Z_1 + Z_3 - 1.$$

I encountered a question asking me to find the joint PDF of $(X2,X3)$, conditional on $X_1 = x_1$.

I know how to compute the the mean vector of them : $$[2\ \   \ 1 \  -1]^T$$ and the covariance matrix of them :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
5&  0& -2\\
0&  5& -1\\
-2&  -1&  2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

However, I don't know how to compute the conditional joint PDF mentioned above.

Comment: Note that $X_2$ is independent of $X_1$ and normal $N(1,5)$, and that $X_3=-\frac25X_1-\frac15X_2+Z_3$ where $Z_3$ is independent on $(X_1,X_2)$ and normal $N(0,1)$ hence $\begin{pmatrix}X_2\\X_3\end{pmatrix}$ conditionally on $X_1=x_1$ is normal with mean $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-\frac25x_1\end{pmatrix}$ and covariance matrix $\begin{pmatrix}5&-1\\-1&\frac65\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the mean and covariance matrix is then computed.

Comment: OK, please explain what you do not "quite understand".

Comment: I understand how the X3 is transformed but how does it help to get the mean and covariance?

Comment: Well, if you fail to see how the mean vector and the covariance matrix can help to describe a gaussian distribution...

Comment: I am sorry. I dont know how

Comment: What do you know about gaussian distributions and about conditional distributions involving gaussian families?

Comment: I know the pdf of gaussian distributions. I think I just dont understand why the conditional variance of X3 is 6/5. should it be var(X3) = (-1/5)*var(X2) + var(Z1)?

Comment: So you think that the variance of $\mathrm{var}(aU+bV)=a\mathrm{var}(U)+b\mathrm{var}(V)$? Hmmm... Reviewing the chapter of your notes on the variance might be a plus...

Comment: oh damn. I think I got it. So it should be: var(X3) = (-1/5)^2 * var (X2) + 1*var(Z3) = 1/5 + 1 = 6/5. like this?

Comment: Much better... $ $

Comment: sorry one more question. When we calculate the conditional mean of X3, we should not take X2 into account? like E[X3] = (-2/5)x1 -1/5* E[X2] = (-2/5)x1 -1/5* 1

Comment: You are conditioning on $X_1$, not on $(X_1,X_2)$.